# pull an item out of an object array in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

I am having a really hard time understanding this. I am selecting all image tags based on whether they have the word `/resize/` in the src of the img tag (I think its returning an array...?). Then I want to check each src to see if there is a file where specified in the src location of that img tag. If the image does exist, then I want to pull out that image from the array, but it won't remove. It's also saying `Uncaught TypeError: images.indexOf is not a function`.

Here is my code -

```
var images = [];
var images = $(' img[src*="/resize/"]');

console.log(images);

$.each(images, function(key, value){
    var getFile = $(value).data('src');
    $.ajax({
        type: 'HEAD',
        url: getFile,
        success: function() {
            var index = images.indexOf(key);

            if (index > -1) {
                images.splice(index, 1);
            }
        },
        error: function() {

        }
    });
    x++;
});
```

Can someone please help? This is killing me...

Comment: Do you know what type of `images`? It doesn't have `indexOf` method.

Comment: So at the end you want to have collection of images which doesn't have corresponding file on the server ?

Comment: Essentially yes dsfq. All of the images already exist in `/files/`. What I'm wanting to do is check if it doesn't exist in `/resize/files/`, if it doesn't then make a refactored array with all the images that have `/resize/` in the src and don't yet exist in that directory, grab the oringinal image files from `/files/ ` and run an ajax crop script, and make it exist in `/resize/files`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `$` (or `jQuery`) constructor returns a jQuery object. jQuery objects behave much like an array with a length, slice method etc. as well as elements indexed 0, 1, 2… etc.

But a jQuery object is **not** a true javascript `Array` and does not have many of the Array methods like `join`, `reverse` or in your case `indexOf`.

Instead you can use the `index` method. [Read more about it on jQuery API Documentation](https://api.jquery.com/index/)

Comment: It is not an `Array` no, as I said it behaves like one, and you can actually call Array methods on a jQuery object (`Array.prototype.forEach.call(y => console.log(y))`).

You actually quite often meet array-like objects. When you use `document.querySelectorAll` a `NodeList` is returned which does not have array methods. Doing `Array.prototype.slice.call(nodeList, 0)` return it as a true array (on which we can then map, filter, reduce etc)

EDIT: Seems like the guy I commented to has deleted his comment, but I'll leave this here.